# How to conditionally remove condition in where clause?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField = 'A' 
and (EndTime > @someTime OR EndTime IS NULL)
```

Above was the original query. Now I have a new condition to see if to take away `EndTime IS NULL`.

```
SET @Throw = 1;

IF @Throw = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField = 'A' 
    and (EndTime > @someTime)
END
ELSE IF @Throw = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField = 'A' 
    and (EndTime > @someTime OR EndTime IS NULL)
END
```

I'm wondering if this can be achieve in 1 query itself or it has to be in 2 query?

Comment: Just for Information, why not place `EndTime IS NULL` as first predicate in OR condition. It helps performance. For example, above code should be:-  `SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField = 'A' 
and (EndTime IS NULL OR EndTime > @someTime )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField = 'A' 
and (EndTime > @someTime OR (@Throw = 0 AND EndTime IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField = 'A' 
    and (EndTime > @someTime AND @Throw = 1) OR ((EndTime > @someTime OR EndTime is NULL) AND @Throw = 0)
```